# mysql like query

Tags: mysql

How do I combine a LIKE query with bind_param,?  I tried:

```
%?%
```

But I'm doing it wrong and I can't find any reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from your_table where your_column like concat('%', ?, '%');
```

and bind the `?` to your input value

The naive approach:

```
select * from your_table where your_column like ?;
$your_input='%'.$your_input.'%';
```

is vulnerable to SQL Injection and should not be used.

Comment: You could also put the `%` around the value that you're binding.

Comment: Beware [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327) with the second one.  If `$your_input` contains '`x%' OR 1 = 1 --`', the query does not perform as you expect.

Comment: lucky me its not via input it's a category view and its all preseted